# Making a duplicate row in SQL table based on condition, and replacing a value in the new row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
Agency    Year    Total   PopGroup
01        2017    3467    3C
01        2018    3444    3C
01        2019    3567    3C
02        2017    1000    1C
02        2018    1354    1C
02        2019    1333    1C
03        2017    6784    2C
03        2018    3453    2C
04        2017    3333    2C
```

If an agency has a row for year 2019, I want to duplicate this row and call it 2020 (basically, an estimate population for 2020).  Desired result:

```
Agency    Year    Total   PopGroup
01        2017    3467    3C
01        2018    3444    3C
01        2019    3567    3C
01        2020    3567    3C
02        2017    1000    1C
02        2018    1354    1C
02        2019    1333    1C
02        2020    1333    1C
03        2017    6784    2C
03        2018    3453    2C
04        2017    3333    2C
```

I think I should use something like:

```
INSERT INTO table
WHERE Year = 2019
```

but I'm a little stuck. What can I try next?

Comment: A little stuck on what? On how to perform an `INSERT`? Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? It has plenty of [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#InsertExamples).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track:

```
INSERT INTO table (Agency, Year, Total, PopGroup)
    SELECT Agency, 2020 as Year, Total, PopGroup
    FROM table t
    WHERE Year = 2019 ;
```

Comment: What does table t refer to? is that an alias? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 . . . It is just a table alias, and not being used in the code.  You can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following insert to add a new row exactly same as another one but with some modified data.

```
insert into table (select agency, 2020, total, popgroup from table where year = 2019)
```

this will insert a new record exactly same as 2019 but with year 2020

Comment: thanks.  Is "table" to be replaced by the name of my table?

Comment: yes, table to be replaced with your table name